# AssertionFailedException while creating Commbobox in tableviewer

Tags: swt, jface, tableviewer

I am trying to make a combobox in table viewer in Eclipse SWT.pointing me in the right direction.I think I've done everything ok until now, problem is the combo box not display in the table,I got error this:

Error:
[image: Error image]
Block of Code is:

```java
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    System.out.println("createPartControl call");

    // For Testing

    Composite tableComposite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    tableColumnLayout = new TableColumnLayout();
    tableComposite.setLayout(tableColumnLayout);
    tableComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true,
            true));

    tableViewer = new TableViewer(tableComposite, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL
            | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    tableViewer.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());
    // TODO viewer.setLabelProvider(new ViewLabelProvider());
    table = tableViewer.getTable();
    // Table table = tableViewer.getTable();
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
    table.setLinesVisible(true);
    String[] titles = { "Threat Name", "Category Name", "Status",
            "Priority", "Description", "Justification" };

    for (int loopIndex = 0; loopIndex < titles.length; loopIndex++) {
        tableViewerColumn = new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer, SWT.NONE);
        TableColumn tblclmn = tableViewerColumn.getColumn();
        tableColumnLayout.setColumnData(tblclmn, new ColumnPixelData(200,
                true, true));
        tblclmn.setText(titles[loopIndex]);
    }

}

   private void fillRows(String shortdesc, String categ, String descp) {
    System.out.println("fillRows call from above method.");     
    TableColumn status_Name_Col = tableViewer.getTable().getColumn(2);
    System.out.println("**************** status_Name_Col ************ "+ status_Name_Col);      
      tableViewerColumn.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider()
        {
            @Override
            public String getText(Object element)
            {
                Dummy p = (Dummy) element;
                return p.getValue();
            }
        });
      tableViewer.addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent selectionChangedEvent)
            {
                StructuredSelection selection = (StructuredSelection) selectionChangedEvent.getSelection();
                System.out.println(((Dummy) selection.getFirstElement()).getValue());
            }
        });


      List<Dummy> elements = new ArrayList<>();
      for (int i = 0; i < Connection.Number_Of_Connection; i++) {
            elements.add(new Dummy("First option"));
        }
      tableViewer.setInput(elements);
      tableColumnLayout.setColumnData(status_Name_Col, new ColumnWeightData(1, true));
      tableViewerColumn.setEditingSupport(new FirstValueEditingSupport(tableViewer));


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assertion message is pretty clear - you must set a label provider for each column in the table.

You don't show us where you are calling `fillRows` but setting the column label provider in that method looks wrong - set the label providers in your loop creating the columns.

Comment: Can you help me.How to set Combo box in only 3rd column?

Comment: You just set the editing supporting for the third column. Don't set editing support on the other columns.

Comment: is there any  way to set combo box in 3rd column? right now no combo box display.

Comment: Editing support only shows the combo when you click on a cell in the column